Analysis and Solution of a Summation Equation Involving polynomial
Suppose that $a_n > 1 \; \text{and}\; b_n>0$, Can the following equation be solved for $x>0$ with general $N$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{a_n x^2}{(x+b_n)(x+b_n+1)}=1.
$$

No solution for $N=1,a_1=1,b_1=1$

@YvesDaoust OP wants $x>0$.

@geetha290krm what if is always $a_k>1$, that is the actual situation with me, I already edited that in the main question.

So far the question is a statement of the problem. Is there anything else you may know about it?

Observe that the function $f:\left[0,+\infty\right)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by: $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N{\frac{a_nx^2}{(x+b_n)(x+b_n+1)}},$$
is strictly increasing. To see that, verify that $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N{a_n\left(1+\frac{b_n^2}{x+b_n}-\frac{(b_n+1)^2}{x+b_n+1}\right)},$$
and so
$$f^{'}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N{a_n\left(\left(\frac{b_n+1}{x+b_n+1}\right)^2-\left(\frac{b_n}{x+b_n}\right)^2\right)}\\
=\sum_{n=1}^N{\frac{a_nx}{(x+b_n)(x+b_n+1)}}\left(\frac{b_n}{x+b_n}+\frac{b_n+1}{x+b_n+1}\right)>0$$
for all $x>0$. Therefore, since $f$ is positive and continuous over $(0,+\infty)$,  it achieves a value of $1$ only once.
Now, if you're looking for an exact value of x, then I cannot help with that.
